# How to fix 'Allowed memory size' when exporting large array data using Laravel Excel 2.1?

Tags: excel, laravel-5.3, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm setting up an export feature based on the generated report, and am having problems when inserting large array rows/data to a sheet using `Laravel Excel 2.1`'s `fromArray` method. Is there any alternate way to do this to not get 'Allowed memmory size exhausted'?

I already tried `array_chunk` method but I'm still getting the memory exhaustion error.

```
$reportData = $this->report->run(); // Depending on the filters of the report, it can get upto 20,000 rows.
$headers = Input::get('selectedcolumns');

$data = [];
foreach($report['data'] as $value) {
    $row = [];
    foreach($headers as $header) {
        $row[$header['label']] = $value[$header['name']];
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}

return Excel::create('Excel', function($excel) use($data) {
    $excel->sheet('Sheet1', function($sheet) use($data) {
        ->sheet->fromArray($data);
    });
})->store('xls', false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in `php.ini` there is variable named `max_post_size`. If the size of the $_POST array increases than set in php.ini, the $_POST array will be empty.
You can use this `ini_set('max_post_size, 50M)` in your script to increase the `max_post_size`. This will set the max_post_size in php.ini for the current request. You can also set the size whatever you want to instead of `50M` given in this example.

Or if you permanently want to increase the `max_post_size` then you should update the `/etc/php/conf/php.ini` file and set `max_post_size` to your desired value.